# Why is connecting to the server with retrofit not working?

Tags: android, laravel, api, android-studio, retrofit

I have tried everything so far I have found on the internet, but I still can't connect to the server. 
Here is the network_security_config file:

```
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel/allamvizsga_backend/public/api/</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I have this included in the manifest file as well.
The error before this was "cleartext communication to not permitted by network security policy" and after the modification it is "Cannot connect to the /127.0.0.1 server". What could be the problem?

My api client interface:

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel/allamvizsga_backend/public/api/";
 public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
     if (retrofit == null) {
         retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .build();
     }
     return retrofit;
 }
```

And a path:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<Result> loginUser(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 refers to the loopback interface on the device you're running the code on. I doubt there's any server running there.

Assuming you have your server on the same computer the emulator is running on, use 10.0.2.2 instead.

For more reading: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking